# How should I approach adding custom themes to a sales management application?

Tags: color-scheme, user-centered-design, font-sizes

I work in a company that develops some of the best sales management tools in the states.

Recently I proposed the idea to add custom themes support which would include:
-different color schemes
-different icon packs
-different font size

I believe this would aid the UX greatly since it could have things that both improve readability and accessibility for everyone and even have color blind oriented stuff to help those who are vision impaired.

How should I approach them with my final pitch? Should I focus on the general public needs or play the humanity card and focus on those who are vision impaired, or go in a totally new direction?

Also if you have any other ideas to add to the custom themes pack(like my font size or custom color scheme idea) I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I would should focus on in which way you could improve your product for your customers and of course the answer to this question is custom themes. Than you sum up your arguments: with custom themes customers can change settings to improve the readability like font size & colors if they are color blind. But custom themes also allow our customers to make the product of their own. Like adding their company's logo and user their company's color scheme. This function (custom themes) will add meaning to our product, the customers will have the feeling that they made their own version of it. Therefore they probably don't want to lose it and go to another sales management application.

Maybe you could add this image to your slide, I got it from the book: Seductive Interaction Design. If you want to stand out of the crowd, your product have to reach Meaningful and custom themes will be a step in the right direction.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a bit of a negative approach, but it's probably the way to go - Focus on how it will impact their business (i.e. financially) if they do (or do not) take on your suggestions.

While people may be interested and agree with preferring that their app being more user-friendly in general, if they can't see how it's going to benefit their business to put time and resource into producing that functionality then they won't go for it. However if you can say 'by providing these templates `x` number of people will now be able to use it where before they haven't been, that means greater uptake of use, which means more money to the company'.

UX designers aren't just there to make systems more usable for people. They're there to make systems more usable for people *because* that has a direct and positive impact to the business (or alternatively because not to do so may result in them getting sued for discrimination against persons of disabilities who can't access the system).

So do some research, find out how the current system impacts people of lower vision (There are web-based tools such as http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html which is a good place to start - even if your app isn't web-based it's still computer-based) and find out what is wrong with the current system, how many people it is impacting and then take it from there.